# Google fonts non-english letters don't use font-weight attribute in safari

Tags: fonts, safari, non-english, roboto

I have a problem with "Roboto" font in Safari (at least on ver. 9.0.3). The problem is that non-english letters like "ąčęėįšųūž" don't use font-weight value when I set font-weight below 400 weight. When it's above 400, it works fine.

[Website in question](http://sabaithai.lt)

Link is correct with weights in it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,400,400italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic%7CRoboto+Slab:100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,400,400italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic">
```

[Example: font-weight: 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIky1.png)

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrote `<meta charset="utf-8">` in head?

If the answer is 'Yes' or the problem remains: 
When 'woff' fonts are from a website, Safari experiences compatibility issues. Try  an OpenType or a TrueType font and this probably won't happen again. You can also download Roboto in your PC.

Comment: Yes, I have utf-8 charset wrote in head.
So woff's are not really compatible with safari then right?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it happens with Safari and webfonts.